# R: use bin counts and bin breaks to get a histogram

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I generated a random vector from normal distribution and plotted a histogram.

I modified the counts of the each bin and I want to plot another histogram with the same breaks(break_vector) and the new bin count vector (new_counts).

How to do that?

I tried barplot(), but the way it displays the bin labels is different.

```
x = rnorm(500,1,6)
delta = 1
break_vector = seq(min(x)-delta,max(x)+delta,by=delta)
hist_info = hist(x,breaks=break_vector)

new_counts = hist_info$counts+5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
new_hist <- hist_info
new_hist$counts <- hist_info$counts + 5
plot(new_hist)
```